# Direct the Image positioning used to as strokeStyle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to use an image as stroke style, but I have a problem on how to direct how the pattern (arrow image) is placed.

For example I used an arrow as pattern for the strokeStyle. I want the arrow to be pointing forward at the top rectangle, point down at the right side, point backwards at the bottom and then pointing up at the right hand side of the rectangle.

More like the image should follow the shape of the rectangle

Using normal stroke just places the arrow in a straight pattern as shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4WHT.png)

This is my code

```
  function drawPattern(img, size) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  const tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

  tempCanvas.width = size;
  tempCanvas.height = size;

  tCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, size, size);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const pat = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "repeat");

  ctx.strokeStyle = pat;
  ctx.lineWidth = 100;
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

const img = new Image();
img.src = "http://freundbild.com/arrow.png";
img.onload = function () {
  drawPattern(this, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a matrix [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) or [DOMMatrixReadOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrixReadOnly) to orientate the pattern using the patterns [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern/setTransform) function.

**UPDATE**

See code for how.

Pattern created in code, but can be an image. Just create the pattern and pass to the following function.

**Note** that the second function is the image the pattern was created from. The example uses a square pattern so the second argument is just the size

**Note** that the pattern is scaled to fit the `lineWidth` so will not maintain its aspect.

```
function orientPattern(ctx, image, pattern, dist, lineWidth, p1, p2) {
    const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    const d = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
    const nx = dx / d;
    const ny = dy / d;
    const w = image.width;
    const h = image.height;
    const yScale = h / lineWidth;
    const mat = new DOMMatrixReadOnly([
        nx, ny, 
        -ny / yScale, nx / yScale,
        p1.x - ((ny * h * 0.5) % h) / yScale - (nx * (dist % w)) , 
        p1.y + ((nx * h * 0.5) % h) / yScale - (ny * (dist % w))
    ]);
    pattern.setTransform(mat);
    return pattern;
}
```

**Note** You need to draw each line segment of the shape you want to draw one at a time. You can not fit it to a rect arc or a path that is not a straight line.

**Note** Line joins will have holes or overlay (depending on the line cap setting) There is  no easy way to overcome this problem without writing a full replacement of the 2D stroke function. That would incur a serious performance hit on rendering this type of path.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createArrowPattern(size, bgCol, col) {
    const c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = c.height = size;
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = bgCol;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, size, size);
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    const u = size / 5;
    ctx.setTransform(size, 0, 0, size, size / 2, size / 2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(-0.4, -0.2);
    ctx.lineTo( 0.1, -0.2);
    ctx.lineTo( 0.1, -0.5);
    ctx.lineTo( 0.4,  0);
    ctx.lineTo( 0.1,  0.5);
    ctx.lineTo( 0.1,  0.2);
    ctx.lineTo(-0.4,  0.2);
    ctx.fill();
    return ctx.createPattern(c, "repeat");
}
    
function orientPattern(ctx, size, pattern, dist, lineWidth, p1, p2) {
    const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    const d = (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
    const nx = dx / d;
    const ny = dy / d;
    const yScale = size / lineWidth;
    const mat = new DOMMatrixReadOnly([
        nx, ny, 
        -ny / yScale, nx / yScale,
        p1.x - ((ny * size * 0.5) % size) / yScale - (nx * (dist % size)) , 
        p1.y + ((nx * size * 0.5) % size) / yScale - (ny * (dist % size))
    ]);
    pattern.setTransform(mat);
    return pattern;
}


function drawPatternPath(ctx, size, pattern, lineWidth, start, ...points) {
    var i = 0;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    var dist = 0;
    var p1 = points[i++]
    while (i < points.length) {
        const p2 = points[i++];
        ctx.strokeStyle = orientPattern(ctx, size, pattern, -start + dist, lineWidth, p1, p2);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();
       // dist += 10
        dist += ((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5;
        p1 = p2;
    }
    

}
const P = (x, y) => ({x,y});
const ARROW_SIZE = 64;
const LINE_WIDTH = 22;
const arrow = createArrowPattern(ARROW_SIZE, "white", "red");
var pos = 0;
animate() 
function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,300);
    drawPatternPath(
        ctx, ARROW_SIZE, arrow, LINE_WIDTH, pos, 
        P(30,30), 
        P(370,30), 
        P(370, 200),
        P(350, 250),
        P(300, 270),
        P(30,270),
        P(30,30)
    );
    pos += 1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width ="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

I consider this approach a hack and that there is a need to map images, patterns, gradients, and text, to strokes (as paths) in the 2D API as at the moment there is no acceptable workaround in both quality and performance.

Alternative option is WebGL which is easily able to draw such patterned paths with excellent speed and exceptional quality however to integrate it with the 2D API is non trivial, and once along that path why bother with the 2D API at all.

Comment: I think they are more looking for something that would really follow the path, like a special dash style i.e which rotates at each corner, even *maybe*(?) split an arrow in two so that it rotates at fits corners too. IIRC there were already Q/As that shown how to do that, but I don't really have time right now to dig that out...

Comment: Hi @Kaiido please I will appreciate if you can help me with a link to that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kadio That is why I gave the function to orient the pattern to a line.

Comment: @Blindman67 your solution was helpful. Thank you . However, it seems not to be compataible with firefox.